# How to find the index of a non repeating list in a list of list without using count?

Tags: python, list, count

Suppose I have a list of lists like this 
`[['a'], ['a'], ['a'], ['b'], ['a'], ['a'], ['a']]`
Now I wish to find the index of the list element that is different from the rest in this case it is `[b]` at index 3.
I have tried using

```
for i in list: 
    if list.count(i) == 1 :
        return list.index(i)
```

to retrieve the index but when the list size grows bigger the time complexity becomes exponentially large as the count function finds the occurrences of each element every time the loop runs.
I was wondering if there is an easy and faster way to get the index of the non-repeating list.
Note: I have also tried making a dictionary with the key as list and value as its number of occurrences, but in this approach, I could not preserve the index of the list which is what I need in my code.

Comment: "I have also tried making a dictionary with the key as list and value as its number of occurrences, but in this approach, I could not preserve the index of the list which is what I need in my code." Please show this attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
for i in range(1,len(list)):
    if (list[1] == list[2]) and (list[0] != list[1]):
        return 0
    if list[0] != list[i]:
        return i
```

This only works if you there is only one item on the list that is the odd one out.

Sorry for the ugly first if statement.

Comment: Your logic would return index of ['t'] in case of [['u'], ['t'], ['t'], ['t']] but the output should be equal to index of ['u']

Comment: Ah yes, that is correct. I've added another if statement to cover that, but logic a little bit ugly now. But it does work.

Answer (score 0):

In case it is useful, here is a version which will start by building up a list of the unique values and which indices they each occur at, before then testing whether the list does indeed consist of a number of common values and a single "odd one out", and if so, give the index of the odd one out.

I could not find a succinct way to do this.  It did not help that the list elements are not hashable objects, so it was not possible to make use of sets.

```
list = [['a'], ['a'], ['a'], ['b'], ['a'], ['a'], ['a']]

# build up a list of 2-tuples of each containing
# (unique value, list indices where this value occurs)

unique_values_and_indices = []
for index, element in enumerate(list):
    for value_and_indices in unique_values_and_indices:
        if element == value_and_indices[0]:
            value_and_indices[1].append(index)
            break
    else:
        unique_values_and_indices.append((element, [index]))

# sort these 2-tuples in order of increasing number of indices
unique_values_and_indices.sort(
    key=lambda value_and_indices: len(value_and_indices[1]))

# check that we have two unique values, one of which occurs at exactly
# one index, and the other of which occurs at more than one index

if (len(unique_values_and_indices) == 2
    and len(unique_values_and_indices[0][1]) == 1
    and len(unique_values_and_indices[1][1]) > 1):

    print("the odd one out occurs at index {}"
          .format(unique_values_and_indices[0][1][0]))

    # # uncomment the following statement for some additional info
    # # beyond what was strictly asked in the question
    #
    # print("the common value is {}, and the odd one out is {}"
    #       .format(unique_values_and_indices[1][0],
    #               unique_values_and_indices[0][0]))

else:
    print("the assumptions were not valid")
```